# Concatenate variables to a String bash script

Tags: bash, shell, unix, curl

I am trying to Concatenate variables with Strings in my bash script, the variables are being read independently but whenever I try to concatenate them, it doesn't recognize the variable values.
ex-

```
echo $CONFIG_PROTOCOL (Prints the variable value, HTTP) 

echo $CONFIG_PROTOCOL'://'$CONFIG_SERVER_SOURCE:$CONFIG_PORT'/api/creation/objects/export?collection.ids='$sf
```

The above echo with the URL prints out /api/creations/objects/export?collection.ids=value_1, while it should print out http://localhost:8080/api/creation/objects/export?collection.ids=value_1

Any inputs will be appreciated.

Comment: Bad problem description: "it doesn't work". Good problem description: "It writes out `://:/api/creation/objects/export?collection.ids=` but I expected `HTTP://example.com:8080/api/creation/objects/export?collection.ids=42`, because as you can see from this paste from my terminal (etc etc)." Please edit your question and add a good problem description

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because `$CONFIG_PORT` has a trailing carriage return. Here's a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve):

```
CONFIG_PROTOCOL="http"
CONFIG_SERVER_SOURCE="example.com"
CONFIG_PORT="8080"
sf="42"

# Introduce bug:
CONFIG_PORT+=$'\r'

echo $CONFIG_PROTOCOL'://'$CONFIG_SERVER_SOURCE:$CONFIG_PORT'/api/creation/objects/export?collection.ids='$sf
```

When executed, this prints:

```
/api/creation/objects/export?collection.ids=42
```

When you comment out the buggy line, you get:

```
http://example.com:8080/api/creation/objects/export?collection.ids=42
```

In both cases, `echo` will appear to show the correct values because `echo` is a tool for showing text to humans and not useful for showing the underlying data. `printf '%q\n' "$CONFIG_PORT"` will instead show it in an unambiguous format:

```
$ echo $CONFIG_PORT
8080

$ printf '%q\n' "$CONFIG_PORT"
$'8080\r'
```

The best way to fix this is to ensure that whatever supplies the value does so correctly. But the easiest way is to just strip them:

```
echo $CONFIG_PROTOCOL'://'$CONFIG_SERVER_SOURCE:$CONFIG_PORT'/api/creation/objects/export?collection.ids='$sf | tr -d '\r'
```

Comment: Just at the same time, I was able to verify that I had properties file in DOS format. It was indeed the line endings causing the issue. Thanks much!

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "$CONFIG_PROTOCOL://$CONFIG_SERVER_SOURCE:$CONFIG_PORT/api/creation/objects/export?collection.ids=$sf"
```

Try above echo statement

Comment: Doesn't work. It still prints /api/creations/objects/export?collection.ids=value_1